# What does 0 (zero) framerate mean in GStreamer?

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I'm trying to learn GStreamer and couldn't understand something.

I saw some test codes from other projects as following,

```
video/x-raw,format=RGB,framerate=0/1
```

What does the `framerate=0/1` in the above `caps` mean?

I tried using `autovideosink` to understand it.
I first expected it to terminate directly
but I see this little flickering frame before it terminates.

So does the `framerate=0/1` not imply zero frames per second?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does say that there is not a constant frame rate set. E.g. it can be variable frame rate (it can still be a constant frame rate - just the information is not set).

This is mostly due to historic reasons. Modern file containers store a timestamp for each frame - so the information of framerate is of no real interest (you can get the approx. by checking how many frames you have and how long the video is).

Older containers like `.avi` require this information set as it is written in its header and none of the frames themselves contain a time information.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! One more question though, then what happens if I use such a `caps` with something like `imagefreeze` that creates a still frame video?